# Always get permission denied on tar. cannot mkdir: permission denied on my kafka installation

Tags: command-line, permissions, chmod, tar

basically this is my question in stack overflow but not answered yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67708710/always-get-permission-denied-on-tar-cannot-mkdir-permission-denied-on-my-kafka

so i just downloaded kafka in binary files (.tgz) and i put that file into my directory /mnt/c:/Program Files/Kafka/

but when i want to un-tar that file with this code

```
tar -xvf kafka_2.13-2.8.0\ \(1\).tgz
```

or even with `sudo`

but i always get notification error

`tar: kafka_2.13-2.8.0: Cannot Mkdir: Permission Denied`

where my wrong at?

updated :
based on @Jagadesh request, here's the result of `ls -al`

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWmQC.png)

i tried with @Jagadesh advice, so i run this :

```
chmod 755 /mnt/c/"Program Files (x86)"/"Kafka"
```

but it produce same thing like this :

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Kafka' : permission denied
```

Comment: One does not simply use `chmod` on an NTFS partition. That's not how permissions work in the Windows world. As for the file that you want to expand, you will need to do so from *outside* the NTFS partition. Copy it to a local directory and then expand it.

Comment: im sorry, i just want to install kafka into my laptop, so based on your advice, what should i do sir?

Comment: If the goal is to install a Windows application, then perhaps you could install it by using Windows? 

Comment: i already handle this problem based on your first advice, thankyou sir, let me put on answer of it

Answer (score 0):

Finally (big thanks to @matigo), After do research, i change the permission on my windows into my users settings to full control, i do this with right click and setting on security based on this article https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/take-ownership-folder-windows-10-using-file-explorer